# Visual Studio c#: copy a tabPage and keep control names

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to duplicate a tab control at design time and then slightly change the names of the controls in the duplicate; I know I've done this once in Visual Studio (without editing the project's "...designer.cs" file).

When I select a TabPage in Document Outline and copy it, then select the TabControl and paste it, it duplicates the page but all the control names go back to things like "comboBox1" and "textBox22". I have names like "X123_Gross_Profit_TextBox", and I want to change the prefixes on the ones on the new tab but not the rest of the name - I'll use Designer to go in, select the name, press the Home key and then the Delete Key a few times, and type in the new prefix.

The really frustrating thing is I've already done this once for another tab in the same project, and distinctly remember the editing operation on the names. But now I can't figure out how I did the copy-paste so that it maintained the names.

As said, I've tried copying from Document Outline and then selecting the TabControl from there and pasting. I've read about "clicking around" on the Designer page until I select a TabPage, but that never seems to work -- I have a bunch of "Dock: Fill" controls and perhaps that makes a difference.

So does someone have a way to do this copy-paste so that I don't have to rekey all the names for the 50-odd controls I have in there? It is such a pain, and somewhat error-prone.

Comment: Why not create a UserControl with all elements you need? Then add it to as many TabPages as needed..

Comment: Can this be done easily and quickly in an application that already exists without UserControls?

Comment: I'd say so.. It is the recommended way to get repeated sets of controls. Best make the controls inside `internal` or go for a nice interface or properties.

Comment: Well, will look into it. Assuming it means I have to change all 6 tabs and scores of existing controls, or their parents or something, I'm afraid it doesn't answer my question directly.

Answer (score 0):

I've now decided this isn't possible. My memory of having done it was faulty; in order to duplicate all the control names, one has to go through the tedium of selecting each one, copying the name, selecting the one to get the new form, then pasting it in and altering it.

I'll look into User Controls for future similar projects.